# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql, casting

I'm getting a sporadic 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String' Exceptions at .SingleorDefault() in the below code. It works 9/10 times but randomly it throws an exception. I made sure that SettingID that i'm passing has no Null Values and the data in the table always exists for the settingID, and i'm always passing SettingID as Integer.

Any ideas what is wrong with this code.

Here is the Exception Info:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.
>        at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_String()
>        at Read_CPT_Setting(ObjectMaterializer`1 )
>        at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext()
>        at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>        at System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
>        at CPT.Service.SettingLinqProvider.GetSettingFromDBById(Int32 SettingId)

CODE:

```
Public Function GetSettingFromDBById(ByVal SettingId As Integer) As ReturnObject(Of Model.ISettingBase) 

    Dim retObj As New ReturnObject(Of Model.ISettingBase)
    Dim dbSetting As CPT_Setting

    Try
        Dim _cptDB As New CPT.Data.CPTLinqRepository.DB(_connString)
        Using _cptDB

             dbSetting = (From s In context.CPT_Settings _
                                  Where s.SettingId = settingId _
                                  Select s).SingleOrDefault

            If dbSetting IsNot Nothing Then
                retObj.ReturnValue = Mapping.Setting.MapDBToModel(dbSetting)
            End If

        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        retObj.ReturnValue = Nothing
        retObj.AddErrorMessage("Error returning the site: " & ex.Message)
        _log.Error(ex.Message, _userId, ex)
    End Try

    If retObj.ReturnValue Is Nothing Then
        retObj.AddErrorMessage("Site Not Found.")
    End If

    Return retObj
End Function
```

---

I've updated the above code with some logging in place after each line.

```
Public Function GetSettingFromDBById(ByVal SettingId As Integer) As ReturnObject(Of Model.ISettingBase) 

    Dim retObj As New ReturnObject(Of Model.ISettingBase)
    Dim dbSetting As CPT_Setting
    Dim SettingsList As New List(Of CPT_Setting)

    Dim errStr As String = " ENTER "

    Try
        Dim _cptDB As New CPT.Data.CPTLinqRepository.DB(_connString)
        Using _cptDB
            errStr &= " - Inside Context "
            If _cptDB Is Nothing Then
                errStr &= " - With Context is Nothing "
                _log.Error("Unusual Object - Unable to create connection object - Object is NOTHING", _userId)
            End If

            If System.DBNull.Value.Equals(_cptDB) Then
                errStr &= " - With Context is NULL "
                _log.Error("Unusual Object - Unable to create connection object - Object is NULL", _userId)
            End If

            errStr &= " - Querying With SettingID = " & SettingId.ToString()

            Dim dbSettingTemp = (From s In context.CPT_Settings _
                              Where s.SettingId = settingId _
                              Select s)

            If dbSettingTemp Is Nothing Then
                errStr &= " -- Nothing is returned from DB - Object is NOTHING -- "
                _log.Error(errStr, _userId)
            End If
            If System.DBNull.Value.Equals(dbSettingTemp) Then
                errStr &= " -- Nothing is returned from DB - Object is NULL -- "
                _log.Error(errStr, _userId)
            End If

            errStr &= " -- Before SingleOrDefault -- "
            dbSetting = dbSettingTemp.SingleOrDefault
            errStr &= " -- After SingleOrDefault -- "

            If dbSetting IsNot Nothing Then
                If System.DBNull.Value.Equals(dbSetting) Then
                    errStr &= " - NULL OBJECT RETURNED - Before Mapping "
                    _log.Error("Unusual Exception - NULL OBJECT RETURNED " & errStr, _userId)
                End If

                retObj.ReturnValue = Mapping.Setting.MapDBToModel(dbSetting)
                errStr &= " - After Mapping With SettingID=" & dbSetting.SettingId.ToString() & " SettingName=" & dbSetting.SettingName.ToString() & " StartDate=" & dbSetting.StartDate.ToShortDateString() & " EndDate=" & dbSetting.EndDate.ToShortDateString()

            Else
                errStr &= " - DBSetting Is Nothing "
                _log.Error("Unusual Object - No Data Retrieved for SettingID=" & SettingId.ToString() & " " & errStr, _userId)
            End If

        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        retObj.ReturnValue = Nothing
        retObj.AddErrorMessage("Error returning the site: " & ex.Message)
        _log.Error("Unusual Exception for SettingID=" & SettingId.ToString() & "--" & errStr & "--" & ex.Message, _userId, ex)
    End Try

    If retObj.ReturnValue Is Nothing Then
        retObj.AddErrorMessage("Site Not Found.")
        _log.Info("Unusual Object - MRDD Solutions - No Data Retrieved for SettingID=" & SettingId.ToString() & " " & errStr, _userId)
    End If

    Return retObj
End Function
```

**Remember: DB has all the rows for all the settingIDs mentioned in below messages.**

**Results:**

**Scenario 1:**

Unusual Object - No Data Retrieved for SettingID=142176  ENTER  - Inside Context  - Querying With SettingID = 142176 -- Before SingleOrDefault --  -- After SingleOrDefault --  - DBSetting Is Nothing

Unusual Object - MRDD Solutions - No Data Retrieved for SettingID=142176  ENTER  - Inside Context  - Querying With SettingID = 142176 -- Before SingleOrDefault --  -- After SingleOrDefault --  - DBSetting Is Nothing

**Scenario 2**

Unusual Exception for SettingID=138145-- ENTER  - Inside Context  - Querying With SettingID = 138145 -- Before SingleOrDefault --  -- After SingleOrDefault -- --Specified cast is not valid.

Unusual Object - MRDD Solutions - No Data Retrieved for SettingID=138145  ENTER  - Inside Context  - Querying With SettingID = 138145 -- Before SingleOrDefault --  -- After SingleOrDefault --

**Scenario 3**

Unusual Exception for SettingID=164638-- ENTER  - Inside Context  - Querying With SettingID = 164638 -- Before SingleOrDefault -- --Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Unusual Object - MRDD Solutions - No Data Retrieved for SettingID=164638  ENTER  - Inside Context  - Querying With SettingID = 164638 -- Before SingleOrDefault --

Comment: What type is the SettingID column in your database?

Comment: Is there a mismatch in types between any of your `CPT_Setting` class's properties and the db table's columns? Like: a column is text and the corresponding property is int.

Comment: Nope. There is no mismatch between the DB columns and the DBML/Class properties. I made sure it is correct with second set of eyes.

Comment: SettingID is an INT NOT NULL column

Comment: I kept more logging in place after each line and came up with some scenarios. Please check these.

Comment: I can't quite wrap my head around all the logging, but in at least one of those cases it looks like SingleOrDefault is returning nothing, which indicates no match was found in the database.  Just as a wild guess, try rewriting the query as Dim dbSetting as CPT_Setting = context.CPT_Settings.Where(Function(C) C.SettingID = SettingID).Single . Single will throw an error if a match is not found.

Comment: I know VB.NET is not case sensitive, but since your parameter is listed as `ByVal SettingId As Integer' then shouldn't the LINQ query read: `Where s.SettingId = **SettingId** _` ? Also the 'CPT_Setting' type probably holds the answer. Is there a property on that type that needs to be nullable and is not? I run into this casting issue all the time in VB.NET trying to use LINQ to objects to dump data into an object that does not have a nullable type. Or possibly there is a varchar type returning an empty string that is being implicitly cast to an Integer property.

Comment: Can you select without the where clause? As if it were a SELECT * ... ?

Comment: Do you compile your code with Option Strict On?

Answer (score 4):

I have followed up with Micorsoft Support and we have enabled debugdiag trace and analyze dump files but could not get anywhere.

After analyzing a lot i found out that 3/4 servers has no latest framework updates so the Server Admins have updated the machines with **Reliability Update 1 for .Net Framework 4** and it seems to have resolved the issue. No code changes has been done. It has been two weeks since the update and did not see a single exception in this code block.

I wasted a month just for this. Darn it. Sometimes it is just not the code.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `ToString()` you have to use `Convert.ToString()`

Hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should check that

```
From s In context.CPT_Settings _
Where s.SettingId = settingId _
Select s
```

does not return more than one object. Perhaps it **never** should, but that might be the problem.

Comment: SettingID is the primary key so it will return only one value. I also tried with .SingleOrDefault as well. The error seems to recurr.

Answer (score 0):

Use single instead of singleordefault?

That was how we resolved a similar situation in work recently.

Comment: I did try that too but it is of no use